# Practical - How can I evenly split teams?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking to split a pool of 16 players (golf) into 2 teams of 8 for an 8 game "season". Teams will be rechosen each week. The idea is to have everyone be on the same team as everyone else the same number of times. I think everyone should be teamates with everyone else 4 times and opponents 4 times, but each person will have 4 people they will only be teammates with 3 times and opponents 5 times. I don't have a math background and havent been able to find a "rotation" that works the way I want it to.

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, why? And if not, what might the "closest" solution be?

Comment: It is not possible exactly. Each player has 7 partners a round for 8 rounds gives 56 partner places, and there are 15 people to fill them but 56 is not a multiple of 15.

Comment: Right. Thats why each player gets shorted with 4 other players that only do a 3/5 split and has 11 players split 4/4 evenly. I've been trying to visualize it as a deck of cards (AKQJ only of 4 suits) where, say, clubs and spades are only teammates 3 times and hearts and diamonds are only teammates 3 times. Every time I think I have it figured out, it turns out I had something dumb like Ace Hearts and Queen Diamonds never on the same team.

Comment: I've also tried working it out like the NFL does their schedule, since they are already in 4 team divisions and have a rotation of the other divisions they play. It's not really analogous, however, because the 8 player teams throw a wrench into it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple system that comes close. Give each player a number $P$, where $P$ runs from $1$ to $16$. Then, for the $G$th game of the season (where $G$ runs from $1$ to $8$), assign player $P$ to "Team Even" or "Team Odd" as follows:

- If $G\times P\mod 17$ is even, put player $P$ on Team Even;
- If $G\times P\mod 17$ is odd, put player $P$ on Team Odd.

For every player, this results in

- six other players with whom they're on the same team $4$ times;
- four other players with whom they're on the same team $3$ times;
- four other players with whom they're on the same team $5$ times;
- one other player with whom they're never on the same team(!).

[The teams this procedure produces can be found here.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98tvyja3dZQx93G1kLHXVtbJ8TVNjg1JzW5JDooMS89NdrQLFbHtSw1L9DBNz8lWlnBXcfQPFYt1jrEH1Odf0oKurKAosy8kmgloDUK6Ym5qQrKSjruOkpWSnCZkNTEXAWQBQqZxQoFOYmVqUXFCkpAZ6CqABqNpsA/Nvb/fwA)

Comment: So, this is definitely very interesting. I think I'm resigned to the fact that getting each player to have 11 other players with a 4/4 split and 4 with a 3/5 split is impossible. However, I'm pretty sure I've found a "pattern" that allows me to have 13 4/4 splits and 2 2/6 splits. I think that's as close as I'm going to get and I'm fairly pleased with it. If somebody has the exact answer, I'd love to hear it.